# Effficent way to do sum and maximum of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, max

I am working on coding challenge where the scenario is
let arr= [6,-2,9]

For day 1, there are no preceding days' information,

Temperature changes = [6] for the before period.
For succeeding days, there are values [6,-2,5] and 6
The maximum of 6 and 9 is 9.

For day 2, consider [6, -2] -> 6 + (-2) = 4, and [-2, 5] -
(-2) + 5 = 3. The maximum of 3 and 4 is 4.

For day 3, consider [6, -2, 5] -> 6 + (-2)+5=9, and
[5]. The maximum of 9 and 5 is 9.

Temperature changes before and after each day:
Day 1: [-1], [-1, 2, 3] -> max(-1, 4) = 4

Day 2: [-1, 2], [2, 3] -> max(1, 5) =5

Day 3: [-1, 2, 3], [3] -> max(4, 3) = 4

Sum each array and take their maximum.

**The maximum from 3 values is [4,5,4]  is 5**

```
tempChange = [6, -2, 5]
result
for (let i = 0; i < tempChange.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        let sum1 = tempChange[0]
        let sum2 = sumArray(tempChange)
        if (sum1 > sum2) {
            result.push(sum1)
        } else {
            result.push(sum2)
        }
    } else if (i == tempChange.length - 1) {
        let sum1 = tempChange[tempChange.length]
        let sum2 = sumArray(tempChange)
        if (sum1 > sum2) {
            result.push(sum1)
        } else {
            result.push(sum2)
        }
    } else {
        let splitArr1 = tempChange.slice(0, i + 1)
        let splitArr2 = tempChange.slice(i, tempChange.length + 1)

        console.log("a1", splitArr1)
        console.log("a2", splitArr2)
        let sum1 = sumArray(splitArr1)
        let sum2 = sumArray(splitArr2)

        if (sum1 > sum2) {
            result.push(sum1)
        } else {
            result.push(sum2)
        }
    }
}

let finalResult = Math.max(...result)
function sumArray(arr) {
    const sum = arr.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
    return sum
}
```

My solution is failing when the array is [ 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 9999999,9999999]

```
Time limit exceeded
Allowed time limit:10 secs
Your code did not execute within the time limits. Please optimize your code. For more information on execution time limits, refer to the environment page
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Already used arr.reduce for sum as you can see in code

Comment: @ControlAltDel - An explicit loop is clearer. Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, `reduce` is just an overcomplicated loop.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly; you have an array of arrays and want to sum the nested array and pick the max of those sums?

Comment: Yes You are getting it corrct Code is not working for big arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the algorithm right from the question, but here's a snippet:

```js
const nums1 = [1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 9999999, 9999999]
const nums2 = [6, -2, 9]
const nums3 = [6, -2, 5]
const nums4 = [-1, 2, 3]


const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
const calc = (nums) => nums.reduce((a, c, i, d) => {
  const s1 = sum(d.slice(0, i + 1))
  const s2 = sum(d.slice(i, d.length))
  const max = Math.max(s1, s2)
  if (a.max < max) a.max = max
  a.change.push(max)
  return a
}, {
  max: -Infinity,
  change: []
})

const nums1Calc = calc(nums1)
console.log(nums1Calc)
const nums2Calc = calc(nums2)
console.log(nums2Calc)
const nums3Calc = calc(nums3)
console.log(nums3Calc)
const nums4Calc = calc(nums4)
console.log(nums4Calc)
```